# Shiny (R GUI) replaces < and > with &lt; and &gt; in tags$script

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny (R GUI) replaces < and > with & lt; and & gt; in tags$script(), how to fix that? I need to use greater and less signs in my javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoops, sorry about that!

You can work around this problem for now by wrapping your script strings in `HTML()`, which will tell Shiny not to escape (this works in any context, not just inside script tags).

Comment: Thanks! It's certainly a better solution than using String(variable-100).substring(0,1)!='-'